# Is my response a valid JSON?

Tags: symfony, json

I am trying to fetch data from my database and convert them to JSON (Symfony2)
Here's what I get as a reply when I visit the json page:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 15:05:03 GMT "[{\"id\":1,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":2,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":3,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":4,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":5,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"},{\"id\":6,\"iam\":1,\"youare\":2,\"lat\":50.8275853,\"lng\":4.3809764,\"msgbody\":\"I saw you over there what's up!\"}]"
```

1. Should I be seeing the actual headers?
2. Is it normal that the double quotes are escaped like that?
3. Should the whole thing be in the form of a file? foo.json?
4. Do you know how to properly convert a Doctrine Entity to JSON?

Comment: no. it's not valid json. the quotes should not be escaped. and if that text is really all a single line, it's not even a valid HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks, I tried also json lint and confirmed that. Wondering why this happens, all I do is serialize and json_encode with Symfony...

Answer (score 0):

You have to download json add-ons for your browser .
like im using chrome json add-on
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en